# How to change rows inside of RenderItem in List? (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to React and this is the code I have:

```
import { List, Avatar, Icon, Layout, Affix, Spin } from "antd";

<List
  split="true"
  itemLayout="vertical"
  size="large"
  dataSource={listData}
  style={{ fontFamily: "Ubuntu" }}
  renderItem={item => (
    <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" md="10" xl="6">
      <Card>-----Content that includes item.description-----</Card>
    </Col>
  )}
/>;
```

I want to render 2 cards in each row, rather than one per row (that's what I get right now). Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: From what I'm seeing in your code, you only have 1 column?

Comment: renderItem iterates through the items from the dataSource. So the code I just posted renders 6 items.

Comment: What is this `List` component? Which library you using

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned. It's antd. Edited the code with the import statement.

Comment: @RajandeepSingh see my answer below, including the example.

Comment: @RajandeepSingh the solution below doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull data from `item` and pass it to `<Card />`

```
import { List, Avatar, Icon, Layout, Affix, Spin, Card } from "antd";

<List
  split="true"
  itemLayout="vertical"
  size="large"
  dataSource={listData}
  style={{ fontFamily: "Ubuntu" }}
  renderItem={item => (
    <Col className="ml-auto mr-auto" md="10" xl="6">
      <Card title={item.title}>
        <div>
          // contet here
          // image here etc
        </div>
      </Card>
    </Col>
  )}
/>;
```

[see this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxidv1)